# How to get which tokens have been transferred by a transaction using ethers or Web3?

Tags: transactions, tokens, erc-721, events, mint

Given for example [this transaction](https://polygonscan.com/tx/0x18d05a3d3940faf302b57dab48f017d5f5800c95e245945f6e1ad36bf11edb90), is there a way of getting exactly what ERC721 tokens have been transferred by it?

To clarify, it would be this detail here:

[image]

Is it possible to get this information using `ethers` or `Web3` via the `txHash`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const { ethers } = require("ethers");

const txHash = "0xabcdef123456...";
const provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider("YOUR_INFURA_ENDPOINT");

(async () => {
    const txReceipt = await provider.getTransactionReceipt(txHash);
    const abi = [ /* ERC721 ABI */ ];
    const iface = new ethers.utils.Interface(abi);

    txReceipt.logs.forEach(log => {
        const parsedLog = iface.parseLog(log);
        if (parsedLog.name === "Transfer") {
            console.log(`ERC721 token ${parsedLog.values.tokenId} transferred from ${parsedLog.values.from} to ${parsedLog.values.to}`);
        }
    });
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

**Get a list of 'ERC-721 Token Transfer Events' by Address**
Returns the list of ERC-721 ( NFT ) tokens transferred by an address, with optional filtering by token contract.

```
https://api-testnet.polygonscan.com/api
   ?module=account
   &action=tokennfttx
   &contractaddress=0xd6f9e7defa52ac67cdfd6a9a352ce6e0a9684b0a
   &address=0xbb282ced765a2a2573747f04101cabd2adab8f45
   &page=1
   &offset=100
   &sort=asc
   &apikey=YourApiKeyToken
```

Usage:
ERC-721 transfers from an address, specify the address parameter
ERC-721 transfers from a contract address, specify the contract address parameter
ERC-721 transfers from an address filtered by a token contract, specify both address and contract address parameters.

Comment: As I said, I have the `txHash` and I want to know what ERC721 were transferred by that transaction, not what ERC721 were transferred by an address (in this case, the address that transferred the tokens is the null address - if I get all the transfers by that address I will just have all the mints that took place and I don't want that).

Comment: ok i understand